# Load a Django template tag library for all views by default

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a small typography related templatetag library that I use on almost every page. Right now I need to load it for each template using

```
{% load nbsp %}
```

Is there a way to load it "globally" for all views and templates at once? Putting the load tag into a base template doesn't work.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is an `add_to_builtins` method in `django.template.loader`. Just pass it the name of your templatetags module (as a string).

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins

add_to_builtins('myapp.templatetags.mytagslib')
```

Now `mytagslib` is available automatically in any template.

Comment: Note that while you can do this, it's quite likely that you'll regret it at some point (I've done it, and regretted it). It makes your templates non-portable to any other project which doesn't add_to_builtins, and it can break tests which render those templates (unless you make sure the test runner also runs add_to_builtins). All in all, it makes things more brittle for a very small gain in convenience.

Comment: Not to mention that any new developer is going to be confuzzled by your use of a tag that doesn't exist in the standard libraries, until they ask you (if you're still around) or stumble upon it. :)  Remember, explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: Can we use this to override default firstof and cycle tag that are XSS faulty? https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17906

Comment: Actually I am using `{% filter force_escape %}{% firstof var1 var2 var3 "fallback value" %}{% endfilter %}` solution now.

Comment: Where do I put this code (ideally) if I want to make the tamplate tag available in my entire project?

Comment: It's better not to use `add_to_buildins` anymore as it is **totally undocumented and can be moved/removed** in any moment without any earlier deprecation. Soon to be released django 1.7 is good examply of it (see [django repo](https://github.com/django/django/commit/34263c67b4315bb326c15d23bdf0363b3a372e17)) - **this solution will not work with django 1.7**.

Comment: With the new import path given below, this approach still appears to be working: from django.template.base import add_to_builtins

Comment: You may have to also add a blank __init__.py file in  appname/templatetags/ directory

Answer (score 41):

It will change with Django 1.9 release.

Since 1.9, correct approach will be configuring template tags and filters under `builtins` key of `OPTIONS` - see the example below:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'builtins': ['myapp.builtins'],
        },
    },
]
```

Details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#django-template-base-add-to-builtins-is-removed

Comment: As of now (Django 1.9), this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `'builtins': ['django.templatetags.i18n'],` oh yeah.

Comment: Im not sure how to link this option to my actual template tag file - and if i need to add anything to my template tag file tor egister it as a built in. There is no documentation on django. Could anyone be kind and edit this answer to provide full details.? thanks

Answer (score 28):

In django 1.7 just replace for `from django.template.base import add_to_builtins`

Comment: Why the downvote? This saved my day, because the accepted answer is outdated! The import path has changed in Django 1.7. Thanks bsao!

Comment: Should this be a comment or an edit on the [existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1185049/1075247) ? It does not make sense on it's own.

Answer (score 6):

In Django 1.9 there is an `libraries` dictionary of labels and dotted Python paths of template tag modules to register with the template engine. This can be used to add new libraries or provide alternate labels for existing ones.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries': { # Adding this section should work around the issue.
                'custom_tags' : 'myapp.templatetags.custom_tags',#to add new tags module.
                'i18n' : 'myapp.templatetags.custom_i18n', #to replace exsiting tags modile
            },
        },
    },
]
```