# Using a Django template_tag on pages that extend from the view that loads the tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I've added a template tag to my app which I load in a view located in `inc/base.html`. This view contains my basic HTML layout. All my other views begin `{% extends "inc/base.html" %}`.

In one of my views I want to refer to my template tag, which is loaded in `inc/base.html` using this code: `{% load spb_utils %}`. If I try to use on of the template tags inside base.html it works fine, but if I try it any other view, it errors unless I manually add `{% load spb_utils %}` to the extended view as well.

Is this behaviour intentional? Eg, if I extend a template, does Django deliberately not load any of the template tags the 'parent' template loads? Is there a smart way to globally load my tags?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is the correct behaviour. extending a template does not load its template tags.

for always loading tags, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185049/105043), though you should carefully consider whether you really want this:

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
[...]
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I realise this removes some of the decoupled nature of Django but at the same time I'm struggling to find a simple, global way to setup (for example) a shared URL variable or whatever. A context processor seems like way more effort than this sort of thing should require. Thanks!