# why is adding a base template breaking my django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm making a website with django and rest framework and I found myself copying and pasting a lot of the same code on every page.  I learned about creating a `base.html` and adding `{% extends 'app/base.html' %}` from http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/.  This worked great for most of my pages but I am having issues with 2 pages that have different forms (but I get the same error for all the forms).  The error is:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /boards/: Invalid filter: 'attr'
>
> error during template rendering in template boards.html, error at line 30

I am confused because when I get rid of the `{% extends 'app/base.html' %}` and just copy the head of base.html into this other page, it works fine.  The headers of the 2 are identical but something within the forms breaks when I try to use the base template.  Its kind of a lot of code to include so I'm not going to include it unless requested.  But hopefully someone has an idea of what the issue could be without seeing my code?

I guess it may be relevant to include that I am using `django-widget-tweaks` with my forms.  I'm not sure if that is at all related to the problem.

Comment: please post the full error and please format your answer to separate the commentry from the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was actually with django-widget-tweaks!  I had `{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}` only in `base.html` but I also had to add it to the individual pages (I am still not really sure why, but it worked).  So each template that extends `base.html` and that has a form on it looks like:

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
    ....
{% endblock %}
```

Apparently just loading widget tweaks in the base doesn't cut it, see the comments for why not.

Comment: Did your local `{% block content %}` use `widget_tweaks`?

Comment: @rrauenza what do you mean by local block content?

Comment: In the actual file you had to add `{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}`, were you using calls `widget_tweaks`?  If so, that is consistent with django -- `extends` doesn't extend `load`'s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647126/using-a-django-template-tag-on-pages-that-extend-from-the-view-that-loads-the-ta

Comment: Oh yes, I added `{% load i18n widget_tweaks %}` to each html file that has a form in it.  I did not know that extending the base template did not extend `load`'s, thanks for pointing that out! @rrauenza