# Webapp2 custom tags

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I am migrating from webapp1 to webapp2 and from python 2.5 to python2.7
I had some custom tags I used with

```
webapp.template.register_template_library('common.templatetags')
```

and registered with:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
register = template.create_template_register()
```

and the corresponding decorator and everything else worked fine

now I need to use webapp2 which does not have template.register.....

I tried doing it this way : http://www.john-smith.me/Tag/webapp2
but it didn't work

thanks

Comment: fixed by using django add_to_builtins() instead of using the undebuggable {%load%} tag
what a waste of time :D

Comment: You know you can answer your own question?

Comment: yes but only after 6hours And now i need to wait 5h to accept my own answer :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solved by using add_to_builtins()

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins

add_to_builtins('myapp.templatetags.mytagslib')
```

Comment: a more detailed answer would be great

Comment: same as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184983/load-a-django-template-tag-library-for-all-views-by-default