# Custom Tags in Django 1.2 with Google App Engine Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, filter, tags

Creating a custom tag in Google App Engine Python2.5 with Webapp used to be a joyful experience. Here: [Django templates and variable attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948/django-templates-and-variable-attributes)

But now, in Python 2.7 with Webapp2 and Django 1.2, it is a pain in the ass. I can only find bits of information here and there, and some of the methods contradict with each other.

The method described in http://www.john-smith.me/Tag/webapp2 ranks high in Google, but some people claim it is "what a waste of time" [Webapp2 custom tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618551/webapp2-custom-tags)

This one method seems to work

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('xxxxx')
```

But I dont know the details. Who can provide a step by step example?

I dont know why there are no official documents about these stuff. I mean, this is not science experiments in which we explore the unknown. There supposed to be some documentation so the developers can save their time.

Comment: I have trouble converting my old app with tag, would definitely love a step by step example!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

The fix:

1. Create templatetags folder. Add there module with custom tags as explained in Django docs [Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/).
   Example folder structure:

   ```
   app.yaml  
       myapp/
           __init__.py
           templatetags/
              __init__.py
              my_tags.py
   ```
2. In settings.py set INSTALLED_APPS to myapp (name of folder which contains templatetags sub-folder):

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = ( 'myapp' )
   ```
3. Now when you call `{% load my_tags %}` in template Django should also seek the mytags module in `myapp/*/templatetags/` folder.