# Make django static tag globally available

Tags: django-templates

I'm trying to make the Django 'static' tag available in all templates. I've tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184983/load-a-django-template-tag-library-for-all-views-by-default):

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('django.contrib.staticfiles') # I've tried each of these
add_to_builtins('django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags') 
add_to_builtins('django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles')
```

But keep getting the following error message:

```
django.template.base.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Template library django.contrib.staticfiles does not have a variable named 'register'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand the question right, I think we were asking the same thing.  Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709803/load-django-static-template-tag-library-globally-without-explicitly-loading-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709803/load-django-static-template-tag-library-globally-without-explicitly-loading-it)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'django.core.context_processors.static',` in your `settings.py` like this:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

Comment: I just tried that but I am getting an "Invalid block tag: 'static'" error (after removing the explicit 'load static tags' calls in my templates)

Comment: do I understand it right - you want `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your templates and are just mixing it up with `static`?

Comment: sorry, should have made myself a bit clearer! I want to be able to use the 'static 'tag (new in django 1.4) without having to load the 'static' tag library in each template. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static

Comment: Oh, ok. Are you sure you've added https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_STORAGE to your `settings` and `collectstatic` everything? Works here out of the box.