# Load Django "static" template tag library globally without explicitly loading it in every file

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-1.4

I want to use the static tag in templates like so:

```
<img src="{% static "img/test.jpg" %}">
```

I've found that that requires me to put

```
{% load static %}
```

at the beginning of every template file.
Since I'm using it everywhere, I would like it to be a globally available tag so I don't need to put {% load static %} to use it.

In my settings I do have:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
```

I saw both of these questions:
[Make django static tag globally available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758401/make-django-static-tag-globally-available)
and 
[Load a Django template tag library for all views by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184983/load-a-django-template-tag-library-for-all-views-by-default)
though neither seems to answer the question.  In the former the question wasn't clear and in the later I get errors when I try to use:

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('django.core.context_processors.static')
```

Perhaps I'm not putting it in the correct location, or perhaps it's already part of the core so doesn't work?

How can I automatically get the static tag added into all template files without explicitly loading it for every file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a lot of answers forget where you need to put the code. Well, let me start by telling you that you can use the following code to get the job done:

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('django.templatetags.static')
```

Now put this, in your main `urls.py` file. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `django.core.context_processors.static` with `django.templatetags.static`:

```
>>> from django.template import Context,Template
>>> from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
>>> add_to_builtins('django.templatetags.static')
>>> Template('{% static "img/test.jpg" %}').render(Context())
'/static/img/test.jpg'
```

BTW, your code has a typo: Replace `add_to_bultins` with `add_to_builtins`.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are old and don't work in Django 3

in settings.py add 'django.templatetags.static' under TEMPLATES -> OPTIONS -> builtins

so with a basic default setup it should look like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': ...,
        'DIRS': ...,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'builtins': [
                'django.templatetags.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

thanks to a blog: https://chris-lamb.co.uk/posts/importerror-cannot-import-name-add_to_builtins-under-django-19