# Django-Angular's djng_rmi template tags do not expand

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates, djangular

I'm trying to use [Django-Angular](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular)'s [djangoRMIProvider](https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/blob/master/docs/remote-method-invocation.rst#template-tag-djng_current_rmi) to give my angular app that sits on top of django access to some django methods.

The snippet I've copied in (and customised the `my_app` name), and added a `console.log` to is:

```
{­% load djangular_tags %­}
…
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("djangoRMIProvider: "+djangoRMIProvider);
my_app.config(function(djangoRMIProvider) {
    djangoRMIProvider
        .configure(
            {­% djng_current_rmi %­} <!--errors here -->
         );
});
</script>
```

It turns out that neither `{­% djng_current_rmi %­}` nor `{­% djng_all_rmi %­}` expand out to what they should.

I've gone as far as copying the Django-Angular file `djangular_tags.py` under:

```
my_app
     ↳ templatetags
         ↳ djangular_tags.py
```

And I'm certain that both `my_app` and `django_angular` (I had to rename the Django-Angular app `djangular` to `django_angular` as there is another package, Djangular, with the app name `djangular` - try saying that ten time fast) are in 'INSTALLED_APPS'.

I even used [this dirty hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185049/1075247) to force the tags into the builtins but either I've done it wrong, or it doesn't work (I do get errors saying it's looking in `django.templatetags.my_app.templatetags.djangular_tags`, which is not right, or other erros, if I put anything but `my_app.templatetags.djangular_tags` in that function call)

Comment: I've had to 'vandalise' the question, as my work filters are blocking posts with 'script' in the body.

Comment: does this script get executed at all ? maybe add a console.log("start"); at the beginning if unsure

Comment: @pixou it's at the bottom of my index.html , I can try mixing it round,  but it should probably go under the django_angular script import

Comment: I meant beginning of this script block, not the page, just to check that is it properly loaded and executed.

Comment: @Pixou no difference...

Comment: so does it get inserted and executed ? still unclear to me if the install was correct, as you say that the console.log does not output anything, which looks like the script is not executed at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77605/discussion-between-pureferret-and-pixou).

Comment: @Pixou I've posted an issue on github, hopefully that will help: https://github.com/jrief/django-angular/issues/165

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{}` for the function declaration confuse django when it looks for tags to inject. By moving it outside of the function declaration, it should work fine.

```
{% load djangular_tags %}
…
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tags = {% djng_current_rmi %} 
    my_app.config(function(djangoRMIProvider) {
        djangoRMIProvider
            .configure(
                 tags
             );
    });
</script>
```