# Load static files for all templates in django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, static-files

Is there a way in django to not need the `{% load static %}` at the top of every template?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184983/load-a-django-template-tag-library-for-all-views-by-default) indicates you can factor out common load tags into settings, but doesn't give the particulars you need in this case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As of Django 1.9, you can add a `builtins` key to your `TEMPLATES["OPTIONS"]` in `settings.py`.

For Django 2.1+, use:

```
'builtins': ['django.templatetags.static']
```

For Django 1.9 - 2.0 (this will work up until 2.2, after which it is deprecated), use:

```
'builtins': ['django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles']
```

For example, the whole template setting might look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'builtins': ['django.templatetags.static'],
        },
    },
]
```

---

Thanks to [@ZachPlachue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59337564/2800876) for the Django 3 update.

Answer (score 6):

The previous answer's method is deprecated as of Django 3.0. (see : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#features-removed-in-3-0)

Now you'd need to add the following to your template settings:

```
'builtins': ['django.templatetags.static']
```

This is the updated templates setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'builtins': [
                'django.templatetags.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the update; I've incorporated it into my answer and given you credit at the bottom

Comment: Thanks! Happy to contribute. Thanks for the initial solution. @Zags