# Django template's include not sharing static files

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a large Django project with multiple templates which are merged later on to construct pages dynamically, I am facing a weird issue as follows:

1. I have a `base.html` which includes all the needed imports, including JS and CSS.
2. I have sub-folders for both CSS/JS in the assets, which are usually imported at the end of `base.html`.

Now, as my project got bigger, I decided I'd rather have the scripts imports, e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/base.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/menus/projects.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/menus/sensors.js" %}"></script>
```

included in each individual HTML file, instead of all being in the `base.html`, I expected to have no issues, since as far as I know `include` statements should also transfer context, for reference sake, those are the `include` statements of interest:

- in `base.html`:

```
{% include "applications/Devices/deviceDashboard.html" %}
```

- in `deviceDashboard.html`:

```
{% include "applications/Devices/deviceDashboard/listCard.html" %}
{% include "applications/Devices/deviceDashboard/editCard.html" %}
{% include "applications/Devices/deviceDashboard/graphCard.html" %}
```

In all of those, if I try to run it as-is I get the following:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Invalid block tag on line 25: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

When I try to use the same script import tags as before, and this issue is gone when I use `{% load static %}` *for each individual page*. I have `{% load static %}` in my `base.html`, but it only applies in that file, and not to any of the sub-files called through the `include` function.

Why doesn't the `include` copy the context here? Or does it not copy "static" by default? I suspect this should be a simple misunderstanding from my part about how `include` is supposed to work here, but I wasn't able to find anything while searching. Finally, if its how import works, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's `load` template tag only loads packages for the specific template file, and are not inherited through `extends` or `include` tags.

See for an explanation [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1193):

> My understanding is that this is a feature, not a bug. The template
> system only provides the tags loaded in each template file itself so
> that templates can be reused without having to guess at what their
> environment expectations are.
>
> A fix for the problem of having to put
> {% load i18n %} in every template might be to add an app-specific
> automatically loaded template setting, so each app author can decide
> what the base namespace for their templates is. This would require
> adding an app-specific configuration system, and somehow letting the
> template module know what the 'current app' is.

If you want specific tags to be available in all templates, you can use the approach used here:
[Load static files for all templates in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837134/load-static-files-for-all-templates-in-django)

Comment: Cheers, mate. It's interesting and makes sense, but its weird how hard to find it was 

Answer (score 0):

**Define static files settings in django project settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
```

**Also add this to your project main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I am... not sure if this is the recommended way to do this, I feel like exposing the media and static files I have like that wouldn't be correct, but I could be wrong. I will need to look this up. However, this still doesn't answer the *why* of the cause of the issue. (And I will test it to see if it solves the issue..)

Comment: I just checked and It has not solved the issue.