# Dynamically determine Django template tags file to be loaded inside {% load %} using a variable

Tags: python, django

I have a set of applications in a Django project all of which have similar templates. In each template for each application, I load the template tags file I have defined for that application:

```
{% load <appname>tags %}
```

But since `appname` is different for every application, it causes the templates (which are identical otherwise) to differ. I can determine `appname` programmatically inside a template, so all I need is a way to do something like this:

```
{% load appname|add:'tags' %}
```

Is such a thing possible? The idea above doesn't work because the result of the expression is parsed directly, rather than being interpreted the way other tags are. The end goal is to have the templates which are the same across all the applications to be shared via soft links, to reduce code duplication.

Comment: What is the problem with ***explicitly*** loading the tags? Remeber "Explicit is better than implicit." is part of the Zen of Python.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea. It makes it unpredictable *what* tags will be loaded, and how these tags will behave.

Comment: The project as a whole behaves quite dynamically, and a lot of source code is already shared between the applications, so the behaviour is not out of the ordinary as far as the project goes. Generally I would rather have less code, which is loaded dynamically, than have lots of duplicate files. Each application only has one set of template tags.

It would be useful to keep the templates identical (i.e. not explicitly loading different tag names) since that would allow me to use the same underlying files, linked from the applications to the project as a whole.

Comment: It seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976904/2323727) might provide a workaround.

Comment: @Ianvdl have you seen the [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) and the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tags? They exist for the reason of making templates DRY / reusable. Your idea of having templatetags with the same name in different apps and loading them dynamically is not very great. It is simply making life difficult for oneself by making **super bad** design decisions.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat - I'm aware of `extends` and `include`, I'm using both at the moment. I'll look into using `extends` to work around this.